# Wrapping a Marionette CollectionView in another element

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'd like to wrap a Backbone/Marionette CollectionView in a span tag so I can style a SELECT element.

When I try:

```
        ProductOptionsView: Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: 'select',
        className: 'prod-options',
        itemView: self.views.ProductOptionsItemView,

        onRender: function() {
            var $option = $('<option data-price="' + self.currentBasePrice + '" value="-1">Select an option</option>');
            this.$el.attr('id', 'options-select');
            this.$el.wrapAll('<span class="sold" /');
<snip~>
```

The call to wrapAll() doesn't happen. If I could just apply all the styles directly to the select tag, I would, but that's not supported. I can't find anything in Marionette or Backbone docs that show how to modify what HTML is actually output from their views.

Or if it would be possible to set a tagname of 'span' and then build a select with options underneath it, I could possibly do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `onShow`, since `onRender` gets called before the view's `el` is added to the DOM.

`view.el` gets appended to the DOM, so wrapping it in `onRender` won't actually do anything.

Comment: That's perfect... but you got me thinking, wrapping it BEFORE it gets injected should be more performant than cloning it, adding a dom fragment and then re-injecting the cloned node, right? Could I do all this before render?

Comment: You could create a [custom region](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#custom-region-types) (assuming your using regions) that does that. Look at the [`open` method](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.region.js#L175)